# A question about Kronecker Product

Tags: kronecker-product

I can' t show the following equality. Could you give some hints?
$$ A^T\big( \psi(t) \otimes I  \big) Q \big(\psi^T(t) \otimes I\big) A= A^T\big( \psi(t)  \psi^T(t) \otimes Q\big) A$$
where

$\otimes$ is the Kronecker product,

$Q$ is a positive semi-definite matrix,
$A$ is a real matrix,

$I$ is the identity matrix.

$\psi(t)$ is the Legendre wavelet function,

$\psi^T(t)$ is the transpose of $\psi(t)$

Comment: Try evaluating one component at a time.

Comment: How? Could you explain more clearly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Definition) of the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), for all $A$ matrices, we have
$$
A = I_1 \otimes A = A \otimes I_1,\tag{$\heartsuit$}
$$
where $I_n$ is the $n \times n$ [identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix). Specially $I_1 = {\begin{bmatrix}1\end{bmatrix}}$.

The [mixed-product property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Properties) of the Kronecker product states that if $A,B,C$ and $D$ are matrices of such size that we can form the matrix products $AC$ and $BD$, then
$$
(A \otimes B)(C \otimes D) = (AC) \otimes (BD). 
$$
In [general](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jam/2013/296185/), if $A_1,\dots, A_p$ and $B_1,\dots,B_p$ are matrices of such size that the following matrix products exist, then we have
$$
(A_1 \otimes B_1)(A_2 \otimes B_2)\cdots(A_p \otimes B_p) = (A_1A_2\cdots A_p) \otimes (B_1B_2 \cdots B_p).\tag{$\spadesuit$}
$$

Since $\psi$ is a Legendre wavelet function, we know that $\psi(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ for all $t$ in the domain of $\psi$, for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. First we decompose $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ by using $(\heartsuit)$ as the following.
$$
\left( \psi(t) \otimes I_n\right) Q \left(\psi^T(t) \otimes I_n\right) = \left( \psi(t) \otimes I_n  \right) \left(I_1 \otimes Q\right) \left(\psi^T(t) \otimes I_n\right).
$$
Then by using $(\spadesuit)$, we find that
$$ \left( \psi(t) \otimes I_n\right) \left(I_1 \otimes Q\right) \left(\psi^T(t) \otimes I_n\right) = (\psi(t)\psi^T(t)) \otimes Q.\tag{$\diamondsuit$}
$$
If $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2 \times n^2}$, then by multiplying both sides of $(\diamondsuit)$ by $A^T$ from left and by $A$ from right, we have the desired result.

> $$ A^T\left( \psi(t) \otimes I_n\right) Q \left(\psi^T(t) \otimes I_n\right)A = A^T \left((\psi(t)\psi^T(t)) \otimes Q\right) A.
> $$

Comment: many thanks.  $[1]$ is $1$x$1$ matrix, isn't it?

Comment: @HD239 Yes, it is.